# $B(0,1) $ isn't totally bounded in $\ell^{1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I've been able to show using Riesz's lemma that $B[0,1]$ isn't totally bounded , and I tried to solve it for $B(0,1)$ , but I wasn't capable of solving it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Because $\ell^1$ is a normed space, $B[0,1] = \overline{B(0,1)}$. Have you seen the fact that if a set is totally bounded, its closure is too?

Comment: Alternatively: if $B(0,1)$ was totally bounded, so would be its subset $B[0,1/2]$ hence (by dilation) also $B[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution: You do not need to kill this neat little exercise with a tool as strong as Riesz' Lemma. Consider the sequence $\frac{1}{2}(e^{(k)})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq B(0, 1) \subseteq \ell^1$ where $\frac{1}{2}e^{(k)}_j := \frac{1}{2}\delta_{kj}$ for all $k, j \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. the sequence of halved unit vectors.

Now observe that
$$
\lVert e^{(m)} - e^{(n)} \rVert_{\ell^1} = \frac{1}{2}(1-\delta_{mn}),
$$
which means that this is $\frac{1}{2}$ if $m \neq n$ and $0$ else.

If $B(0, 1)$ was totally bounded, then we could cover $B(0, 1)$ with finitely many balls $B\big(x_k, \tfrac{1}{8}\big)$ where the $x_k$ are appropriate points. There must be one ball $B\big(x_j, \tfrac{1}{8}\big)$ in which there are infinitely many members of $\frac{1}{2}(e^{(k)})$. Because of being in that ball, they have at most distance $\frac{1}{4}$. But we have already seen that the distance between distinct members of the sequence is $\frac{1}{2}$. So our set is not totally bounded.

If a metric space has a totally bounded subset $A$, then every sequence in $A$ has a subsequence that is Cauchy.